# After iOS 5 install, only some purchased ringtone transfer to iPhone

Tags: ios, ringtones

After install of iOS 5 on my iPhone 4, I noticed that only 2 of my ringtones installed. I resynched. I explicitly requested a sync of my 7 purchased ringtones. Same result: iTunes synced the same 2 of 7.
I'm on OS X 10.6.8.

How can transfer all of my ringtones to my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Similar thing was reported on Apple's forum (don't have the reference handy).  One guy said he fixed it by: deselect all ringtones, sync, select again, sync.  Another guy said he fixed it by downloading a single new ringtone.

Answer (score 0):

I used iTunes to drag-and-drop from Library/Ringtones onto the iPhone icon in the sidebar. Other restore attempts failed.